# I don't understand how to return a variable in js. XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, api

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', requestURL)
xhr.onload = () => {
    const data = (JSON.parse(xhr.response))
}

xhr.send()
```

Is it even possible to return "const data".
I need use that json anyway

Answer (score 0):

Return the value via a promise. Wrap the code in a promise and return the promise.

```
function httpCall(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject){
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open('GET', requestURL)
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if(xhr.status == 200) {
                 const data = (JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                 resolve(data); 
            } else {
                 reject("Failure to fetch data.");
            }
        }

        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

And call the function via a async / await call.

```
async function makeHttpCall(){
  const data = await httpCall();
  console.log(data);
}
```